# How to Create Element in XSLT When Copying Using Templates

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to create an element in an XML where the basic content is copied and modified.

My XML is something like

```
<root>
  <node>
     <child>value</child>
     <child2>value2</child2>
  </node>
  <node2>bla</node2>
</root>
```

The number of children of node may change as well as the children of root.
The XSLT should copy the whole content, modify some values *and* add some new.

The copying and modifying is no problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(+ further templates for modifications).

But how do I add a new element in this structure on some path, e.g. I want to add an element as the last element of the "node" node. The "node" element itself always exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="node">
    <node>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <newNode/>
    </node> 
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Adding a child to the root element doesn't work using this. Any solutions?