# where to put a customised second web.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven, tomcat

I want to create this simple schema:

I am writing a maven application that gets deployed as a war to the server. I want to have the same web.xml for my localmachine and the server and add individual context params according to the machine.

Right now I do this by putting them in Tomcat's global web.xml but this gets propagated in all applications running (which is working but it's obviously not the right way to do).

Can I add web.xml parameters for a specific webapplication ? some setting in context.xml somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

As an exercise (I hadn't the chance to use this in production yet) I tried to pack a different (transformed) web.xml in the final WAR based on different profiles.

You can check my own question and its answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25960351/3127111).

Comment: I just found my other question about how to transform the XML, [here's it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25957167/3127111)

Comment: its not exactly what I want because in the web.xml i want to keep stuff like ELASTIC_CLUSTER_IP or RABBIT_MQ_IP and an admin can change them and restart tomcat. I do not want developers to chose the profile and the settings.

Comment: @arisalexis I see. Well, maybe in this case you could be better reading those parameters from the environment / a configuration file at runtime? I.e. from a listener?

Comment: ok but what is the correct way to do this? put a configuration file where (outside of the war) ?  I have an initial listener and I could read these.

Comment: @arisalexis Talking about configuration files I think they should go inside the WAR. If it is mandatory that the artifact should not be touched, I'd use the server environment (how to change it is up to the server admins, you just read the environment settings in your web app).

Comment: it's helpful but could you give me an example of how to set environment variables? you mean running tomcat with -Dvariable ?

Comment: @arisalexis I never did this in practice, so I can't help you very much, however you can read environment variables with [System.getenv](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html). That's what I meant. E.g. you query for a certain variable, if it exists, you take its value, otherwise you fall back to a default.